# Print url when element is a link in Python-Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, getattribute, linktext

I'm using Python3 and Selenium. The xpath below points to a link. I would like to print the URL. If I write `print(link.text)` I get the displayed text portion of the link only.
For example: `link.text` in the following link would give me "link text" when I want URL.

HTML:

```
<a href="url">link text</a>
```

Code trials:

```
path = f"/html/body/div/section[5]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[{str(n)}]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a"
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath(path)
print(link.url)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
link.get_attribute('href')
```

instead of

```
link.text
```

Answer (score 1):

`print(link.text)` would print the text / textContent / [innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072) of the `<a>` [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) i.e.

```
link text
```

If your usecase is to print the value of the *href* attribute i.e. **url** you can use the following solution:

```
print(link.get_attribute("href"))
```